# how to properly test VueJS using cypress with istanbul code coverage when NODE_ENV=test

Tags: vue.js, cypress, istanbul

I am using cypress for E2E testing.

I am using Istanbul to calculate code coverage

**The above combination works well** until I set `NODE_ENV=test` because in `tests/e2e/plugins/index.js` I need to use

```
require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
```

When `NODE_ENV=test`, I don't think VUE compiles the source code, webpack is not used, and hence I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

If I don’t differentiate between prod and test then my production code will also be instrumented by Istanbul, which I don't want to happen.

Can anyone tell me if I am missing something obvious here? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The line in `tests/e2e/plugins/index.js` just facilitates gathering of coverage data, but doesn't instrument the code.

This article has a section on [Conditional instrumentation](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/07/20/code-coverage-vue-cypress/),

> We do not want to instrument the production code.
> Let's only instrument the code when `NODE_ENV=test`

```js
// babel.config.js

const plugins = []
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  plugins.push([
    "babel-plugin-istanbul", {
      // specify some options for NYC instrumentation here
      // like tell it to instrument both JavaScript and Vue files
      extension: ['.js', '.vue'],
    }
  ])
}
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ],
  plugins
}
```

I don't know why you are getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

It may be you've added the task initiator in `tests/e2e/support/index.js` by mistake, since `require()` is only valid in a Node.js environment.

`/plugins/index.js` is in Node.js, but `/support/index.js` is in the test browser.